# How to export store in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react and redux ... so please forgive me for noobie mistakes. I read several documentations of redux and came to conclusion that this is how i should store state of react component. I require redux because there are many more nested components which need quick access of data. however... when I try to export store ... I can't find how to do so.


**My App.js**

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    xx: null,
    yy: null
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      //some logic
    // State gets data from api
    this.setState({
      xx: someval,
      yy: someval2
    });
  }
  render() {
    const obj = {
      xx: this.state.xx,
      yy: this.state.yy
    };

    userReducer(obj,updateUserDetails());

    const store = createStore(userReducer);

    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
        <UserDetails props ={this.state} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

// Reducer function
export const userReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log("in reducer " + JSON.stringify(state));

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_USER_INFO':
      state = {
        ...state,
        xx: action.payload.xx,
        yy: action.payload.yy
      }
      break;
  }

  return state;
}

// Doesn't work
export const store = createStore(userReducer)

// Action
export const updateUserDetails = () => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_USER_INFO'
  }
}
```

I can't figure out way to export store so that it is accessible to nested components. Kindly help
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any answer here will not help you understand the fundamental principles and how to get it all setup with your react app. I suggest you go through this article https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/setting-up-a-redux-project-with-create-react-app-e363ab2329b8 to get the answer to your issue

Comment: Hi, I tried similar thing to what you suggested but the problem is the store should be initialized with data which it is getting from api. that is a complex logic written in App.js which I would not like to move/change. So I thought I should populate initial state of reducer here itself.

Comment: The initial state should be empty, in your `App.js`, in `componentDidMount()` dispatch an action that will update the state. That is the best practice for working with react/redux.

Comment: and one more things it is considered a really bad practice to call functions that update states or make API calls in your `render()`, in order words the `render()` should be a pure function. Rather call those functions in a lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

From looking on your code, I can see a few issues that each one can be your problem.

while reducer first loads, it has to hold initial value for the state to begin with, not related to the one you want to be set at component mount

---

```
    // assiging empty obj as initial value
   export const userReducer = (state = {}, action)
```

---

Actions of redux are higher order functions, returning object to be dispatch

---

```
export const updateUserDetails = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
 return dispatch ({
  type: 'UPDATE_USER_INFO'
 })
```

}

---

About your `createStore`, declare here as well initial value

---

```
 // assign empty obj as initial value
export const store = createStore(userReducer, {})
```

---

hope it is helpful, anyhow I recommended on looking through the docs again